# "Contribute for" or "Contribute to" or "Contribute on" or "Contribute in"

Tags: grammar, phrasal-verbs

We said :

> I do want to thank Mr. Foulen and Mr. Felten who **contribute for**
>   server hosting .

or

> I do want to thank Mr. Foulen and Mr. Felten who **contribute to**
>   server hosting .

or

> I do want to thank Mr. Foulen and Mr. Felten who **contribute on**
>   server hosting .

or

> I do want to thank Mr. Foulen and Mr. Felten who **contribute in**
>   server hosting .

Comment: I think you need to tell us what you intend it to mean. Do they (partially or entirely) supply the hosting itself?  Or do they supply financial or other assistance towards the hosting? Or do they contribute (ideas, for example) in the area of server hosting? Any of your 4 sentences *could* be ok, as could leaving the preposition out ("contribute server hosting") if they supply the hosting itself.

Comment: Another option is "contribute towards".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I do want to thank Mr. Foulen and Mr. Felten who **contribute** server hosting.

The server hosting is what Messrs Foulen and Felten contribute, so there is no preposition; it is the object of the verb.

In doing so, they are contributing *to* the project, and also contributing *to* the beneficiaries.

Unless they were offering an opinion, in which case they did indeed contribute *on* server hosting, though it would be clearer as "who contribute on the topic of server hosting".

Quite likely all of this would be better in the simple past (*contributed* rather than *contribute*) even if their contribution is ongoing.

Comment: What is this great answer ?.ohhhh ! thank you 100..0 times . Congrats!

Comment: I think "to something" is implied in all these cases, so the correct preposition is "to", but might be left out if what is being contributed to is implied.  e.g. "they contributed (to the project) by providing server hosting"

Comment: No, because you're adding a new object there so you've a different object so you're talking about how *to* is the correct preposition in completely different sentences.

Answer (score 0):

According to what I saw in the article below, "contribute to" is a better option. However, "contribute" without proposition is also explained in the article:

[https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/contribute#:~:text=Examples%20of%20contribute%20in%20a,win%2C%20everyone%20has%20to%20contribute](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/contribute#:%7E:text=Examples%20of%20contribute%20in%20a,win%2C%20everyone%20has%20to%20contribute).

In this website (which is a credible website) there are a couple of examples, which only used "contribute to" or "contribute" in different occasions, e.g.

1. We'd like to thank all who contributed their time and effort.
2. Many people contributed to the fund-raising campaign.

Comment: You should include the key points of the article because links can rot.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/412833)