# In furthering or to furthering

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

Which of these sentences is correct?

1)Internet technology has significantly contributed ***to furthering*** education in the world.

2)Internet technology has significantly contributed ***in furthering*** education in the world.

If only one is correct, does this mean that the other one is grammatically wrong or it can be used in a certain context?

Comment: Contributed to - sounds more correct.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Contribute for" or "Contribute to" or "Contribute on" or "Contribute in"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/177054/contribute-for-or-contribute-to-or-contribute-on-or-contribute-in) Actually, I doubt it. But some evidence of research _is_ required. eg [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/contribute): '_The following authors contributed to this issue_: ... or  ' [Textranch](https://textranch.com/222643/contributed-to-the-process-of/or/contributed-in-the-process-of/). But especially Google ngrams.

Comment: Contrary to the suggestion in your title, the correctness of "to" rather than "in" has nothing to do with "furthering" and everything to do with "contributed".